# Exposing Redis Service on EKS Cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-eks

I am running Redis Cluster on EKS as a statefulset and the service is headless. Everything is working properly but the backend application has a test which need to access the host url during the build process. I have tried to expose service with ingress, but still not working. Can you please suggest me some solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? Not all of them can do TCP services.

Comment: AWS ingress controller

Comment: AWS ingress controller provisions a ALB, which can not do TCP. You can create an NLB using that controller by doing a service with `type: LoadBalancer` instead of an ingress, which does do TCP.